# Caching variables in Python (or Neovim)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, neovim

## Caching variables in Python (or Neovim)?

Suppose I initially wrote this in Python:

```py
class Scraper:
    def scrape_data_slowly(self, url):
        # scraping here...

    long_list_of_urls = ["https://some.thing", ..., ...]
    raw_data = [self.scrape_data_slowly(url) for url in long_list_of_urls]
```

And now, I want to implement:

```py
parsed_data = [parse_data(data) for data in raw_data]
```

Obviously, while testing out my new `parse_data` function, I don't want to repeatedly scrape URLs. Is there a better way to accomplish this than writing and opening data to a file while commenting out the first block of code in this example?

I'm looking for something like `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)` which does not seem to work here since we need to save data for the next time we run the program.

Or what AI suggested:

```py
import shelve

class Scraper:
   def __init__(self):
       self.cache = shelve.open('cache.db')

   def scrape_data_slowly(self, url):
       if url not in self.cache:
           # Perform the slow scraping operation here
           self.cache[url] = raw_data
       return self.cache[url]
```

But the problem is that I only need this while developing and I don't want to mess up code because of it. I feel like there is something obvious I'm missing here...

Thanks!

Comment: I would pickle the `raw_data` and comment the slow scraping out (or put it into an `if False` so any linter reminds you to change it back afterwards)